# Bootstrap troubles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I believe i am totally doing it wrong. I try to get a simple layout working but i want to adjust the margins so that there is not such a big gap vertically between "soort" and "plaats".

my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/doubleotwo/2m8wdxba/

```
xxx
```

You can just regard the code which is obviuously very bad... But look at the fiddle to see what im trying to get.

Just 2 rows. With that autocomplete box consisting of an input and a seperate button... this with the knowledge that the form will be used inside a modal popup of width 600px till 800px ( if this is relevant )

EDIT:

I just updated the fiddle and i hope this is kinda correct ?

http://jsfiddle.net/doubleotwo/2m8wdxba/

Now  the question remains to get the vertical gap smaller

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are whats causing the problem.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts

Shows 2 layouts, You should use the one which is seperated

```
|------|-------|
|      |       |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

Like that so the selects are on the left and the check boxes are on the right, Then the checkbox height cant effect the select padding

Comment: just edited my thread, so you say my checkboxes are creating the gap... it seems so now i look at it, your link fixes that ?

Comment: you are right, adding checkbox-inline reduces the problem, but still the checkboxes are "low" in contrast with the input next to it, updated the fiddle